# How to read environment variables in Scala

Tags: scala, environment-variables

In Java, reading environment variables is done with `System.getenv()`.

Is there a way to do this in Scala?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

Since Scala 2.9 you can use `sys.env` for the same effect:

```
scala> sys.env("HOME")
res0: String = /home/paradigmatic
```

I think is nice to use the Scala API instead of Java. There are currently several project to compile Scala to other platforms than JVM (.NET, javascript, native, etc.) Reducing the dependencies on Java API, will make your code more portable.

Comment: It's probably better practice to use `sys.env.get("VARIABLE")` which will give you an `Option[String]` rather than throw an error if that variable is missing.

Comment: @CristianVrabie I would prefer it also, in most cases. But `sys.env` is just a `Map`. You can whatever method is appropriate for you.

Comment: `sys.env.getOrElse("VARIABLE", "default value")` was also helpful in my case where the environment variable may not be defined.

Answer (score 137):

There is an object:

```
scala.util.Properties
```

this has a collection of methods that can be used to get environment info, including

```
scala.util.Properties.envOrElse("HOME", "/myhome" )
```

Comment: I would also prefer Properties. It allows to retrieve Optionals, and has names for commonly used properties.

Answer (score 25):

Same way:

```
scala> System.getenv("HOME")
res0: java.lang.String = /Users/dhg
```

Comment: Now that I use Scala on a daily basis, I must move the accepted answer to @paradigmatic's answer. It uses Scala API and if used as suggested in the comments can return an Option.

Answer (score 22):

Using directly a default with `getOrElse` over the `sys.env` Map (`val myenv: Map[String, String] = sys.env`):

```
sys.env.getOrElse(envVariable, defaultValue)
```

You get the content of the `envVariable` or, if it does not exist, the `defaultValue`.

Answer (score 5):

If Lightbend's configuration library is used (by default in Play2 and Akka) then you can use

`foo = "default value"
 foo = ${?VAR_NAME}`

syntax to override foo if an environment variable VAR_NAME exist. 
More details in https://github.com/typesafehub/config#optional-system-or-env-variable-overrides

Answer (score 1):

To print *all* environment variables, you can use

```
System.getenv.forEach((name, value) => println(s"$name: $value"))
```

Comment: `error: missing parameter type` on the args if you just copy-paste this.

Comment: @thundergolfer: I currently don't have Scala installed on my machine. Did you figure out what was missing?

Comment: After changing the parameters to `(name: String, value: String)`, I'm getting `error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, String) => Unit
 required: java.util.function.BiConsumer[_ >: String, _ >: String]`.

Comment: Here's something that works, but requires an import: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-java-system-environment-variables-properties

Comment: `sys.env.foreach(tuple => println(s"$tuple"))` is not as elegant but seems to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.props.getOrElse("key", "default")` for Java systems properties.

```
  package scala

  object sys {

  /** A bidirectional, mutable Map representing the current system Properties.
   *
   *  @return   a SystemProperties.
   *  @see      [[scala.sys.SystemProperties]]
   */
  def props: SystemProperties = new SystemProperties

  /** An immutable Map representing the current system environment.
   *
   *  @return   a Map containing the system environment variables.
   */
  def env: immutable.Map[String, String] = immutable.Map(System.getenv().asScala.toSeq: _*)
```