# Specify a different build.sbt file in jenkins (scala)

Tags: scala, jenkins

Is there a way to specify a different file other than build.sbt when compiling with scala?

I want to be able to have 2 different files:
-> dev.sbt
-> prod.sbt

There are some docker configurations I need to have different in each file that are environment specific.

Comment: What configurations? Can't you specify that with the same .sbt file and different targets or build options?

Comment: I don't believe so. I was hoping to have in the build.sbt. 

FROM image_dev
FROM image_prod

based on the environment that the build is going to from Jenkins.
Do you know of documentation to outline how to do that in the build.sbt?

Comment: Can't you just add that as an environment variable?

Comment: ahhh like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406013/sbt-how-to-access-environment-variable-or-configuration