# Is there any special support for environment variable access in Ammonite?

Tags: scala, ammonite

I'm wondering if ammonite has a convenient, shorthand way to access environment variables from the parent process, or is `scala.util.Properties.envOrElse` the suggested method? ([How to read environment variables in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997292/how-to-read-environment-variables-in-scala))

Related: is there a way to list all current objects in ammonite? Somewhat analogous to `env` in bash, though possibly different, as it seems that environment variables are not imported as vals or vars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `sys.env` (Scala default import - available in Scala REPL too). You can use the `show` function in ammonite to avoid truncation in printed output.

Example:

`show(sys.env)`

`sys.env("HOME")`